# AddSingleton<>() vs AddSingleton()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

I'm implementing dependency injection in my project. I've come across two ways to add a singleton service -

```csh
services.AddSingleton(new MyCustomService())
```

and

```csh
services.AddSingleton<MyCustomService>()
```

Both methods seem to work. What's the difference between these two methods, and which one should I be using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using the generic `.AddSingleton<TService>()` method (and `.AddSingleton<TService, TImplementation>()`, the type is created, controlled, and disposed of by the container. When the constructor contains other dependencies, those dependencies are automatically injected (a technique called "Auto-Wiring").

Instances supplied using `.AddSingleton<TService>(TService)` already exist. In that case, the container will **not dispose of** that instance when it implements `IDisposable` or `IAsyncDisposable`. You are responsible for disposing of that instance yourself.

Since `.AddSingleton<TService>(TService)` is supplied with an already existing instance, the container can't inject any dependencies, because in order to do that, it must also *create* the instance.

When instances are registered using the `.AddSingleton<TService>(Func<TService>)` method, the `Func<TService>` delegate is in control over the creation of the dependency, but the instance returned by the delegate will still be tracked and disposed by the container.

Comment: How about `.AddSingleton<TService>(Func<IServiceProvider,TService>)`? I would assume that when using that method, the type is also created, controlled and disposed by the container. Is that correct? Even if I use an explicite `new`, such as `services.AddSingleton<MyCustomService>(_ => new MyCustomService())`, right?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addsingleton?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) in first sample, you are using `AddSingleton<TService>(IServiceCollection, TService)` extension method, and in second one - `AddSingleton<TService>(IServiceCollection)`.

The difference between this 2 is the time when the instance of `TService` is created. In first one - you create it upon registration. In second one - it will be created be container on first request.

It's up to you which one you should use. But if your `MyCustomService` may have additional dependencies - I guess `AddSingleton<TService>(IServiceCollection)` maybe more handy.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: explicit loading of a service versus using generics to pull from injection via configuration.

In the first instance, you are adding a SingletonService you are instantiating yourself. In the second, you are asking dependency injection to load up MyCustomService based on configuration. The latter is useful when you might have different versions of MyCustomService for different configurations of the application.

Another way of looking at it. The first is loading a singleton and fails if it is not. The second is using generics to validate the type of service and will blow up if there are none specified in configuration.