# how AddSingleton<TService, TImplementation>() works

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm new to dependency injection,I've come across this line code in an asp.net core project

```
services.AddSingleton<TService, TImplementation>()
```

And I'm confused 'TService, TImplementation' is used to tell the compiler that the generic type that will be returned or/and passed to the method I'm i right ? but the method in question does not take any parameters what I'm missing ? should not the method look something like this :

```
services.AddSingleton<TService, TImplementation>(TService a,TImplementation b)
```

this question is already asked [AddSingleton<>() vs AddSingleton()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62078023/addsingleton-vs-addsingleton) but the answers are not clear to me , can someone please explain how this work ?

Comment: What exactly do you not understand in the linked questions answer? In the variant without the argument, the dependency injection framework will create (or get) the implementation object `TImplementation` for you when you request the `TService` interface.

Comment: it works more like declaratively, generally the service type ***is required*** (service type is the type you use at design time or called the design-time dependency type). The implementation type is the runtime type which has its instance created and injected in-place of the service type references (in constructors, properties, ...). It just need the types mapping to do its job. Sometimes, creating an instance requires a factory so you can provide it a factory instead. Finally, sometimes you already have the instance so just register that (instead of the implementation type).

Comment: there is one special case in which service type and implementation type are the same. It's the case you use `AddSingleton<T>` or `AddSingleton(someInstance)`. The service type (for the latter usage) is derived from the type of `someInstance` (a feature supported by the compiler).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method takes two type parameters `TService` and `TImplementation`, and zero method parameters.

The full signature and implementation of this method looks something like

```
public static IServiceCollection AddSingleton<TService, TImplementation>(this IServiceCollection services)
    where TService : class
    where TImplementation : class, TService
{
    if (services == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));
    return services.AddSingleton(typeof(TService), typeof(TImplementation));
}
```

The type parameters tell you as a developer that you should expect any resolution of a `TService` by the IoC container is going to return you a single instance of a `TImplementation`. The type-safe check of `where TImplementation : class, TService` says the actual class returned must implement (or be a) `TService`.

How the actual `TImplementation` is created, is up to the container, and dependent on zero or more constructor parameters on `TImplementation`'s constructor.

Your question, "should not the method look something like this", is generally going to have the answer "no". The reason is that that signature requires you to have two actual objects (actually maybe a single one passed twice) *already constructed*, which usually defeats the purpose of dependency injection in the first place.

Type parameters *do not have to correspond* to actual method arguments, though they often (usually) do. In this particular case, the type parameters themselves are passed into another method as actual arguments of type `Type`, which are then used by the rest of the IoC implementation to create the right object.

So why do they do this and not just have `services.AddSingleton(Type serviceType, Type implementationType)`?. The answer lies in type safety. This signature is not type safe as you could call `services.AddSingleton(typeof(Animal), typeof(House))` which doesn't make sense and would fail at runtime. In contast, `services.AddSingleton<Animal, House>()` wouldn't even compile.